# Using Sections in TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

How do you pass data from a `tableview` Controller with sections to a `ViewController`? I can do it when I'm not using sections, but the program crashes when I use sections? And I don't understand.

This is the error message I get and it cranes with a `SIGABIT` message on this line:

`NSString *mytempName = [NSString stringWithString:[tempObject charName]];`

Error message:

```
2014-07-24 06:38:05.465 Passing_Data_With_Two_Sections[469:60b] -[__NSArrayM charName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f0d230
2014-07-24 06:38:05.501 Passing_Data_With_Two_Sections[469:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM charName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f0d230'
```

Here is the code from the TableView Controller

```
#import "myTableView.h"

@interface myTableView ()

@end

@implementation myTableView

NSMutableArray *myHeadersArray;
NSMutableArray *myFightersArray;
NSMutableArray *myLadiesArray;
NSMutableArray *myArray;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    myHeadersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Fighters", @"Ladies", nil];

    myFightersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    myLadiesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    objectFile *myObject = [[objectFile alloc]init];
    myObject.charName = @"Peter Pan";
    [myFightersArray addObject:myObject];

    myObject = [[objectFile alloc]init];
    myObject.charName = @"Mikey Mouse";
    [myFightersArray addObject:myObject];

    myObject = [[objectFile alloc]init];
    myObject.charName = @"Mrs Duck";
    [myLadiesArray addObject:myObject];

    myObject = [[objectFile alloc]init];
    myObject.charName = @"Mini Mouse";
    [myLadiesArray addObject:myObject];

    myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:myFightersArray, myLadiesArray, nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [myHeadersArray objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [myHeadersArray count];
    //This seems to crash if you go above 2. Which I assume is somehow tied in with the sections.
    //Adding additional names now no longer crash. But if I changed it to myArray then it crashes
    //bitching it being greater 2.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [myArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = ((myTempObjectFile*)[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).charName;

    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    int myrow = [path row];
    myTempObjectFile *tv = [myArray objectAtIndex:myrow];
    vc.tempObject = tv;
}
@end
```

And here is the code from my ViewController:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myLabelOutput;
@synthesize tempObject;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *mytempName = [NSString stringWithString:[tempObject charName]];
    [myLabelOutput setText:mytempName];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you try to invoke method `charName` for an array.
As I see you store arrays in array and you should change implementation to:

```
myTempObjectFile *tv = [[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
vc.tempObject = tv;
```

or just

```
myTempObjectFile *tv = myArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] 
vc.tempObject = tv;
```

This answer to your question.

But I think that here we need to refactor: not very beautiful to store arrays in an array, it is better to make an abstract object for this data structure. And tempObject name does not bear any semantic meaning.

Comment: thanks for responding. I'm guessing this should be done in the segue? If so I get this error message: "use of undeclared identifier 'indexPath'; did you means 'NSIndexPath?'